# Ignore json null value in System.Text.Json Deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

model：

```
public class Demo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; } = "Default value";
}
```

json strJson：

```
{
    "A" : 1,
    "B" : null
}
```

When I using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize

```
var obj1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Param>(strJson, new JsonSerializerOptions() { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull });

obj1.B is null
```

I want obj1.B is "Default value".
This code can be useful

```
var obj2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Param>(strJson, new JsonSerializerOptions() { IgnoreNullValues = true });

obj2.B is "Default value"

but IgnoreNullValues is obsolete from .net core 6 version
```

in .net core 6+,is any other way ignore null in Deserialize？
Or as the WhenWritingnull name suggests,is When Writing null,not When Reading null.
Or does the dotnet team believe that if the fields in JSON explicitly have null values, we should not manually ignore them?

Comment: @PoulBak The strJson is not something I can control, but comes from a third-party API

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you for reply,but my questions is skip read json null value when deserialize,because read value will be set value to Model Setter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution in MSDN [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts)

This code available

```
static void InterceptNullSetter(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
{
    foreach (JsonPropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
    {
        Action<object, object?>? setProperty = propertyInfo.Set;
        if (setProperty is not null)
        {
            propertyInfo.Set = (obj, value) =>
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    //value = ((Demo)obj).B + value;
                    setProperty(obj, value);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() {
    PreferredObjectCreationHandling = JsonObjectCreationHandling.Populate, //If Model.property is collect and this config is Populate,then skip propertyInfo.Set
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { InterceptNullSetter }
    }
};

var o1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Demo>(json, serializerOptions);

//Now,when json any field value is null will be skip Setter
```

Comment: PS: Only .NET 7+

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @JeremyCaney My English proficiency is very average. It is recommended to directly refer to the MSDN official documentation and link it in the answer. The principle of this code is very simple, starting from. net 7, System Text Json JsonSerializer supports intercepting models during serialization and deserialization Setter and Getter for Property, and then perform custom processing

Answer (score 0):

To avoid setting `null` to your property, you can write your property like this:

```
private string b;
public string B 
{ 
    get => b;
    set => value ?? b;
} = "Default value";
```

Comment: This solution is available,but my project is using third-party OpenAPI auto-generate too many model class.maybe use JsonConverterFactor and override CanConvert method can be useful,I'm trying

Comment: CanConvert method don't work,God,I think only use Utf8JsonReader manual deserialize json string,Utf8JsonReader have Skip() method and TrySkip() method.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something to handle a null bool that came in from a third party that had not read the spec.  To handle a null string value in .NET 6 and have a default value, it's like this: -

```
using System.Text.Json;

public class Demo
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private string _b = "Default value";
        
    public string B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        // Allow setting of an empty value, but disallow a null:
        set { if (value != null) _b = value; }
    }
}
```